# Deployment in Amazon VPC with custom gems hosted inside company's network

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, capistrano, amazon-vpc

I have a very interesting problem. Following is my current workflow of deployment in Amazon EC2 in classic mode.

1. Deploy host inside my Company's network.
2. Deploy Target is EC2 machine in AWS.
3. Have custom ruby gems inside the company's git account (Hence cannot install gems from outside my companies network).
4. To overcome the problem mentioned in Point #3. I have used reverse tunnelling between the deploy host and deploy target.
5. I am using capistrano for deployment.

---

Now the problem arises when we decided to move from Amazon Classic to Amazon VPC with deploy target having only private ip address. Here is the workflow I thought of for deploying code in VPC instances.

1. Create a deploy host in Amazon VPC and attach public dns to it so that I can access it from my main deploy host (which is inside my company's network.)
2. Deploy the code by running the deployment scripts from  AWS deploy host.

The problem is that I am not able to find a way to install gems which are hosted inside the git account of my company. Can you guys help me with this problem?

Comment: Did you consider to cache that gem in our vendor folder?

Comment: Isn't your VPC also in your company network ?

Comment: @Rico: No the VPC is not inside the company network. Is there a way to    do it?

Comment: @spickermann: Thanks. I will explore this option.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to deployment, you can just setup git mirrors of your production repositories by just pushing to git bare repositories in your AWS deploy host.

Then that AWS deploy host also has access to your VPC so you can do the deployment from there.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Download the gems first and then pass it to the ec2 instance in vpc using scp

```
scp -r -i key ubuntu@ip-address:/ruby-app
```

Then run `gem install gem-name` from the folder, it will install gem from within the folder matching with the name.

Run `bundle package`, this will download all the gems and will be present in `vendor/cache` folder. Now move this files to the ec2 instance.